# What is ORing and why is it named ORing?

Tags: power-electronics, circuit-protection, texas-instruments, poe

I read some documents like the PoE application, it used ORing to protect the reverse input current. I would like to know what ORing is. I googled it, but I cannot find the answer.  It seems like a diode or something the datasheet uses diode to protect, but I am not sure what this is.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: In the power supply context, ORing uses a logic term to describe an analogue circuit function, described well by @TomCarpenter answer below.

Comment: Or-ing, not O-Ring, in case that's how you were reading it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have seen O-Ring mentioned in a presentation in front of the entire engineering department.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OR is a logical function - the output is high when either input is high.
ORing is simply a way of saying perform the logical OR of a set of signals.

In the context of power supplies, when ORing is used, the output (the device) is powered by whichever supply typically has the highest voltage.

A simple power OR gate can be made by diodes in series with each supply, which prevent power from the higher voltage supply backflowing into the lower voltage supply.

Comment: So, I can not only use a diode to do the OR function right?

Comment: EEC- No, there are other techniques besides diodes that can be used.  FETs are used quite often as they offer lower ON resistance and so lower voltage drop than a diode.

Comment: Hi SteveSh
Do have some related documents? I'd like to read.

Comment: @EEC [this](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/a-low-loss-replacement-for-an-oring-diode.html) might be a good read. Product specific, but it gives some insight. Keyword: "Ideal Diode" and "Load switch"

Comment: I parsed it a O-Ring and wondered what it was talking about.

Comment: @Joshua - I couldn't decide between `or-ing`, `o-ring` and `0-ring`. These all sound _just_ like they could be a specific technical term. :D

Comment: @Joshua [O-ring](https://i.imgur.com/o1rhMOO.jpg), usually used as a seal to couple two parts. Very common part.

Comment: And it's named `OR`ing because the result is high if input 1 **OR** input 2 is high.
Compare with `AND`ing where the result is hight if input 1 **AND** input 2 are high.
There's also `XOR` (exclusive OR: result is high if input 1 **OR** input 2 is high, **but not both**), and negations (`NAND`, `NOR`)... Of course in this specific case where it's not really the logic but the power that matters, those probably wouldn't make much sense.